# how to move Ubuntu 20.04 partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

Let me explain my situation

I have some chunks for unallocated space in my disk which I want to use but `Microsoft Reserved Partition` is coming between it. On consulting with windows experts I got to know that the 16mb partition is for the future and I can copy-paste it easily.

[image]

Now what I want is to move my ubuntu partition 5GB to the right and paste the Reserved partition there but I am getting a warning that the system might not boot.

Can anybody provide a safe procedure for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I do not think that GParted will allow you to move, (cut/paste), a partition through an existing partition. You might be able to copy/paste it, then delete the original once you see everything is still working. Back everything up first

Comment: Your description of what you want to do does not make any sense to me.... you may want to rewrite that...  i can't even guess. You may want to add a little more detail or describe the goal or what the end picture looks like....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Moving Ubuntu System Partition

You should have no problem moving the Ubuntu system partition, I have never had an install fail by doing so. It is still a good idea to backup the drive.

- Boot a Live Ubuntu USB or DVD.
- in GParted right click the partition and select `Resize/Move`.
- Make `Free space preceding (MiB)` = 5000
- Right click the Microsoft Reserved Partition and select `Copy`.
- Right click the free space and select `Paste`. You can expand the partition to fill the space if desired.
- Click the green check mark to `Apply All Operations`.
- Delete the original Microsoft Reserved Partition.

Comment: Ohh wow is it really that easy. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

looking at your Gparted screenshot - there's no need to move things around as you should be able to extend Ubuntu 300 GB partition without issues.

Things such as "move a partition 5GB to the right" are not supported in GParted and are generally not supported.

To achieve such effect:

1. backup everything on a separate HDD / Storage via image copy of /dev/sda - you need to boot CD / USB live distro to achieve this
2. delete the partition you'd like to move way you describe
3. create a new empty partition starting at your desired location
4. use dd to transfer the backup data to a newly created partition
5. check everything and maybe update grub(?)